# Password protect web directory with htpasswd on Cherokee

Tags: linux, web-server, authentication, cherokee

I have a directory on my Cherokee webserver that I am trying to password protect so that when I try to enter it from a web browser, I get a pop up demanding username and password.  Needless to say I am getting stuck.

I have created the .htaccess file with:

```
AuthUserFile /srv/http/protected
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Protected Stuff"
AuthType Basic

Require valid-user
```

And I used the apache-tools' htpasswd command:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd wdkrnls
```

I configured Cherokee with a behavior rule on the /protected directory which requires htpasswd authentication and restarted.  I get `Error 405 Method Not Allowed` whenever I navigate there in a directory.

What more do I need to do?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Cherokee don't support Apache mod_authn_file directives. You need use cherokee-admin to configure htpasswd authentication:
[image]

Comment: I had this already.  What appeared to be one part of my problem was that I had every rule listed as [Final].  When I made them not final, I got the prompt I had been expecting.  However, I still cannot see the files in the directory.

Comment: "IP_ADDRESS/protected/" 404 Not Found? Do you correct set "Document Root" and "Document Root" exist? Do you set "Handler" to "Static content"?

Comment: Maybe it’s also an issue of denying directory listing? "see the files". Try opening a file directly.